# how to i establish socket.io connection only AFTER logging in , REACT + socket.io

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-context

can i get help with something im stuck on for awhile
im establishing a socket .io connection in my frontend with react context,
but the connection is triggered as soon as my web load, i want it to connect only AFTER i login
im running a jwt auth on my socket connection and what happens is it fails to auth because i dont have a chance to login before it checks it
and then after i log in it wont establish connection untill i manually reload the page...

client:

```
import React from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client'

import { SOCKET_IO_URL } from '../api/config';


const jwt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'))?.token
 
console.log(jwt)
export const socket = io.connect(SOCKET_IO_URL, {query: {token: jwt}});



export const SocketContext = React.createContext()
```

server:

```
io.on('connection', (socket => {
  const token = socket.handshake.query.token;
  try {
    if (!token) throw new Error("TOKEN NOT FOUND")
    jwt.verify(token,'secret') 
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('VERIFICATION FAILED')
    socket.disconnect()
  }
  console.log('socket conected', socket.id)

  socket.on('request_fetch', () => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('response_fetch')
  })
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import the socket / use the socket only in areas where you are logged in.

And lazy import those components

const Dashboard = lazy(() => import('./pages/Dashboard'))

that way the token will always be available when loading those components

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs in the client options, there is an option `autoConnect`

[Client Options](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-options/)

Set this to `false` as it defaults to `true` then manually try to connect after you have logged in with `socket.connect`